Hyperbolic geometry undecidability proof in lean 4 help
trying to reduce the halting problem to hyperbolic geometry to prove the undecidability of hyperbolic geometry, having problems with the diagonalization of the Turing machines, also missing some axioms for hyperbolic geometry. and tbh i have no idea what the unexpected token means. I've tried taking the comma out in several places, all of them, just in that line, doesn't solve it. primarily, can someone help me solve the diagonalization problem?
The code is here:
import Mathlib.Tactic
import Mathlib.Data.Real.Basic
import Mathlib.Data.List.Basic
import Mathlib.Data.Finset.Basic

-- Suppress linter warnings for unused variables
set_option linter.unusedVariables false

open Classical -- Use classical logic for decidability

-- Define a Turing Machine
structure TuringMachine (states symbols : Type) where
  transition : states → symbols → states × symbols × Bool -- Transition function
  startState : states -- Start state
  haltState : states -- Halt state

-- Define finite states and symbols
inductive TMState
| q0 | q1 | halt
deriving DecidableEq, Fintype

inductive TMSymbol
| zero | one | blank
deriving DecidableEq, Fintype

-- Example Turing Machine
def tm_example : TuringMachine TMState TMSymbol := {
  transition := fun state symbol =>
    match state, symbol with
    | TMState.q0, TMSymbol.zero => (TMState.q1, TMSymbol.one, false)
    | TMState.q1, TMSymbol.one => (TMState.halt, TMSymbol.one, true)
    | _, _ => (TMState.halt, TMSymbol.blank, true),
  startState := TMState.q0,
  haltState := TMState.halt
}

-- Execution of a Turing Machine for a number of steps
noncomputable def TuringMachine.execute {states symbols : Type} [Fintype states] [Fintype symbols]
    [DecidableEq states] [DecidableEq symbols]
    (tm : TuringMachine states symbols) (steps : ℕ) (input : List symbols) :
    Option (states × List symbols × Bool) :=
  let rec step (currentState : states) (tape : List symbols) (remainingSteps : ℕ) :
      Option (states × List symbols × Bool) :=
    match remainingSteps with
    | 0 => none
    | n + 1 =>
      match tape with
      | [] => none
      | symbol :: rest =>
        let (newState, newSymbol, halt) := tm.transition currentState symbol
        let newTape := newSymbol :: rest
        if halt then
          some (newState, newTape, true)
        else
          step newState newTape n
  step tm.startState input steps

-- Input for the Turing Machine
def input_example : List TMSymbol := [TMSymbol.zero, TMSymbol.one]

-- Explicit Definitions for States and Symbols
def orderedStates : List TMState := [TMState.q0, TMState.q1, TMState.halt]
def orderedSymbols : List TMSymbol := [TMSymbol.zero, TMSymbol.one, TMSymbol.blank]

-- Poincaré Disk Model
structure PoincareDisk where
  x : ℝ
  y : ℝ
  hyp_condition : x^2 + y^2 < 1 -- Point lies strictly inside the unit disk

namespace PoincareDisk

-- Geodesics
structure Geodesic where
  center : ℝ × ℝ -- Center of the defining circle
  radius : ℝ -- Radius of the circle
  is_diameter : Bool -- True for diameters, False for orthogonal arcs

-- Membership of a point on a geodesic
def onGeodesic (p : PoincareDisk) (g : Geodesic) : Prop :=
  if g.is_diameter then
    p.x = g.center.1 -- Diameter case
  else
    (p.x - g.center.1)^2 + (p.y - g.center.2)^2 = g.radius^2 -- Orthogonal arc case

end PoincareDisk

-- Encode TuringMachine states and symbols as hyperbolic geometry configurations
noncomputable def TuringMachine.encodeAsGeometry (tm : TuringMachine TMState TMSymbol) (input : List TMSymbol) :
    List PoincareDisk × List PoincareDisk.Geodesic :=
  -- Map states and symbols to unique ℝ values
  let stateToReal (state : TMState) : ℝ :=
    orderedStates.indexOf state + 1
  let symbolToReal (symbol : TMSymbol) : ℝ :=
    orderedSymbols.indexOf symbol + 1

  -- Encode state as a PoincareDisk point
  let encodeState (state : TMState) : PoincareDisk :=
    { x := 0.9 * Real.sin (stateToReal state * 0.1),
      y := 0.9 * Real.cos (stateToReal state * 0.1),
      hyp_condition := by
        have h : Real.sin (stateToReal state * 0.1)^2 + Real.cos (stateToReal state * 0.1)^2 = 1 :=
          Real.sin_sq_add_cos_sq (stateToReal state * 0.1)
        linarith [h] }

  -- Encode symbol as a geodesic
  let encodeSymbol (symbol : TMSymbol) : PoincareDisk.Geodesic :=
    { center := (0, 0),
      radius := 1 / (symbolToReal symbol + 2),
      is_diameter := false }

  let states := orderedStates.map encodeState
  let geodesics := input.map encodeSymbol
  (states, geodesics)

-- Undecidability Proof for Turing Machine Execution
theorem TuringMachineExecutionUndecidable :
  ¬(∀ (tm : TuringMachine TMState TMSymbol) (input : List TMSymbol),
    ∃ steps, tm.execute steps input = some (tm.haltState, [], true)) := by
{
  -- Assume decidability of halting for contradiction
  intro h_decidable,

  -- Define a diagonal Turing Machine that alternates indefinitely
  let diagonal_tm : TuringMachine TMState TMSymbol := {
    transition := fun state symbol =>
      match state, symbol with
      | TMState.q0, TMSymbol.zero => (TMState.q1, TMSymbol.one, false) -- Move to q1
      | TMState.q1, TMSymbol.one => (TMState.q0, TMSymbol.zero, false) -- Back to q0
      | _, _ => (TMState.halt, TMSymbol.blank, true), -- Default to halt
    startState := TMState.q0,
    haltState := TMState.halt
  }

  -- Input for the diagonal machine
  let input := [TMSymbol.zero, TMSymbol.one]

  -- Assume the diagonal machine halts (contradiction setup)
  have h_halts : ∃ steps, diagonal_tm.execute steps input = some (diagonal_tm.haltState, [], true),
  { exact h_decidable diagonal_tm input }, -- From assumption of decidability

  -- Extract steps and result from halting assumption
  cases h_halts with steps h_steps

  -- Prove that the diagonal machine cannot halt
  have h_contradiction : diagonal_tm.execute steps input ≠ some (diagonal_tm.haltState, [], true),
  {
    induction steps with
    | zero =>
      -- Base case: 0 steps mean  no execution, so the machine cannot halt
      simp [TuringMachine.execute] at h_steps,
      contradiction
    | succ n ih =>
      -- Recursive case: analyze the machine's step-by-step execution
      simp [TuringMachine.execute] at h_steps,
      cases input with
      | [] =>
        -- If the input is empty, the machine cannot proceed, so it cannot halt
        simp [TuringMachine.execute] at h_steps,
        contradiction
      | symbol :: rest =>
        -- Simulate the first step of the machine
        cases diagonal_tm.transition diagonal_tm.startState symbol with
        | (new_state, new_symbol, halt) =>
          by_cases halt
          -- Case 1: Halt = true leads to contradiction, as diagonal_tm loops indefinitely
          { simp [*] at h_steps, contradiction }
          -- Case 2: Halt = false, continue recursion using IH
          { apply ih, assumption }
  },

  -- Conclude contradiction
  exact h_contradiction h_steps,
}

-- Test the Geometry Encoding
noncomputable def encoded_geometry := TuringMachine.encodeAsGeometry tm_example input_example

the errors im getting are these
errors:
mathlib-stable.lean:120:0
unsolved goals
h_decidable : ∀ (tm : TuringMachine TMState TMSymbol) (input : List TMSymbol),
  ∃ steps, tm.execute steps input = some (tm.haltState, [], true)
⊢ False

mathlib-stable.lean:122:19
unexpected token ','; expected '}'

